# How do you the change font size of the fields via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, fonts, google-forms

I want to make the font size of a Google Form smaller using Google Apps Script. I've looked on-line but can't find any reference to it. Is it possible? If not with GAS, is it possible some other way? It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks.
Baz

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. Any luck so far?

Comment: No, I've been told for now it's not possible. A form made as a web app would be the only possibility.